# Скриншот html блока программно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть ли способ получить скриншот блока (например на странице есть определенный div) только через код?

Есть библиотеки которые делают скриншоты когда запущен браузер. Но мне нужно получить картинку отправляя запрос с сервера. То есть что то что запустит код как будто в браузере и сделает скриншот.

---

У меня есть ссылка на документ 
https://site.ru/files/index.html

И селектор. 
.div_block_preview

Вот имея эти данные как мне получить картинку предпросмотра на сервере? (желательно выбирать еще вид браузера)

Comment: Обновил вопрос, на более конкретный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). Код примерно следующий.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("url", function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        //Heres the actual difference from your code...
        var bb = page.evaluate(function () { 
            return document.getElementsByClassName("span7 demo")[0].getBoundingClientRect(); 
        });

        page.clipRect = {
            top:    bb.top,
            left:   bb.left,
            width:  bb.width,
            height: bb.height
        };

        page.render('capture.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
  }
});
```

Comment: А как установить этот webpage  phantomjs?
В npm это совсем другой модуль webpage.

Comment: Код не работает.

Comment: У них на сайте есть готовый пример https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

Comment: Ошибка и там и там.
    return decorateNewPage(opts, phantom.createWebPage());
                                 ^
ReferenceError: phantom is not defined

Comment: Где подключать сам phantom?

Comment: http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Не могли бы вы привести пример кода на node js в своём ответе, чтобы он перестал выдавать ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Можешь сделать что то подобное по аналогии с этим кодом

```js
$(".drag").draggable();
$(".drag").droppable();
var takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("container"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var tempcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
            tempcanvas.width=350;
            tempcanvas.height=350;
            var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(canvas,112,0,288,200,0,0,350,350);
            var link=document.createElement("a");
            link.href=tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');   //function blocks CORS
            link.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
            link.click();
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#container{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}
#rightcontainer{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:gray;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:110px;
    padding:10px;
}
#leftmenu{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    padding:10px;
}

button{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.drag{
  width:40px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:100000;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  
  
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">Snapshot</button>
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftmenu">
      Left Side
      <div class="drag">
      </div>
      <div class="drag">
      </div>
      <div class="drag">
      </div>
      Drag----------->
            &
      Click Snapshot
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
        Right Side
    </div>
</div>
```